# How to update a column by repositioning the values in a random order

Tags: sql, oracle, random

Okay, so this table will work as an example of what I am working with. This table consists of the name of someone and the order they are in compared to others:

| NAME | ORDER |
| --- | --- |
| ZAC | 1 |
| JEFF | 2 |
| BART | 3 |
| KATE | 4 |

My goal is to take the numbers in ORDER and reposition them randomly and update that into the table, keeping the NAME records in the same position that they were in originally.

Example of the desired result:

| NAME | ORDER |
| --- | --- |
| ZAC | 3 |
| JEFF | 1 |
| BART | 4 |
| KATE | 2 |

Using the table above, I have tried the following solutions:

#1

```
Update TEST_TABLE
Set ORDER = dbms_random.value(1,4);
```

This resulted in the random numbers between 1 and 4 inclusive, but the numbers could repeat, so ORDER could have the same number multiple times

Example of the attempted solution:

| NAME | ORDER |
| --- | --- |
| ZAC | 3 |
| JEFF | 1 |
| BART | 3 |
| KATE | 2 |

#2

```
Update TEST_TABLE
Set ORDER = (Select dbms_random.value(1,4) From dual);
```

This resulted in the same random number being copied into each ORDER record, so if the number came out at 3, then it would change them all to 3.

Example of the attempted solution:

| NAME | ORDER |
| --- | --- |
| ZAC | 3 |
| JEFF | 3 |
| BART | 3 |
| KATE | 3 |

This is my first time posting to StackOverflow, and I am relatively new to Oracle, so hopefully I proposed this question properly.

Comment: Can you please let us know what do you mean by "keeping the NAME records in the same position that they were in originally.", do you mean there is an another column on which you are order in the ID or you mean just the was the data is returned by the Query or is it how it is stored in the DB. In Oracle if you want data to be displayed then it is always better to specify the ORDER BY clause and also  data is not stored by any specific order in the DB.

Comment: @HimanshuKandpal Maybe that was some bad wording on my part. What I meant by that was that I only wanted to update the values in ORDER. The new values must be a random number between 1 and 4 and the number can't be the same on different rows. 

Only the ORDER column needs to be updated not the NAME column.

Comment: What is the primary key on the table? NAME, ORDER, NAME and ORDER, or something else?

Comment: @JonHeller I should have just used an id instead of name for the example, but for simplicity sake, Name would be the pk in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```sql
MERGE INTO test d USING
  (SELECT rownum AS new_order,
          name
     FROM (SELECT *
             FROM test
            ORDER BY dbms_random.value)) s
   ON (d.name = s.name)
 WHEN matched THEN
   UPDATE
     SET d.sort_order = s.new_order;
```

The new order is build by simply sorting the original data by random values and using `rownum` to number those random records from 1 to N.

I use `NAME` to match the records, but you should use the primary key or `rowid` as in Littlefoot answer.
Or at least an indexed column (for speed, when the table contains a lot of data), which uniquely identifies a row.

Comment: In the actual table that I’m working with, it does have a pk that I am using, and I should have put that in place of name for the example. But this seems to solve my problem. You guys are all amazing!

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test order by rowid;

NAME    C_ORDER
---- ----------
Zac           1
Jeff          2
Bart          3
Kate          4
```

Table is updated based on value acquired by the `row_number` analytic function which sorts data randomly; matches are found by the `rowid` value:

```
SQL> merge into test a
  2  using (with counter (cnt) as
  3          (select count(*) from test)
  4         select t.rowid rid,
  5                row_number() over(order by dbms_random.value(1, c.cnt)) rn
  6         from counter c cross join test t
  7        ) b
  8  on (a.rowid = b.rid)
  9  when matched then update set
 10    a.c_order = b.rn;

4 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test order by rowid;

NAME    C_ORDER
---- ----------
Zac           3
Jeff          4
Bart          1
Kate          2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to sort the data randomly and join on the "name" column:

```
merge into data dst 
using (
    select rownum as rn, name from (
        select name from data order by dbms_random.value()
    )
) src
on (src.name = dst.name)
when matched then
    update set ord = src.rn 
;
```